# Is it possible to Create/Delete Python Panel main element in ReactTemplate from a User Button Click?

Tags: python, reactjs, panel

I'm coding in Python.
I want to be able to let the user customise his Dashboard. I'm using **Python Panel** library, and it's ReactTemplate base on React-grid-layout (js). I wanted to know if there is a way that on a **button click**, a **new div** could appears. Then the user could choose from different options of plots/parameters.

Like this [example](https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/6-dynamic-add-remove.html) : which is in JS.